# Problem changing icon in Tkinter using the adequate format

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

I've been having some trouble changing the icon of the window using Tkinter. The code I've written is the following:

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Learn To Code with me, Mario')
root.iconbitmap(PhotoImage("/home/pablo/Desktop/Python utilities/Interfaces/Exercises/Pictures/Untitled.ico"))

e = Entry(root, width = 35)

root.mainloop()
```

The error that appears is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-da0866f0b787> in <module>
      1 root = Tk()
      2 root.title('Learn To Code with me, Mario')
----> 3 root.iconbitmap(PhotoImage("/home/pablo/Desktop/Python utilities/Interfaces/Exercises/Pictures/Untitled.ico"))
      4 
      5 e = Entry(root, width = 35)

/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py in wm_iconbitmap(self, bitmap, default)
   2069             return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, '-default', default)
   2070         else:
-> 2071             return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
   2072 
   2073     iconbitmap = wm_iconbitmap

TclError: bitmap "/home/pablo/Desktop/Python utilities/Interfaces/Exercises/Pictures/Untitled.ico" not defined
```

I've tried different methods that I've found across the Internet, but nothing that could actually solve my issue, because the format of the image is the adequate one (*.ico)

Comment: Just pass the path of ico to `iconbitmap()` directly.

Comment: @acw1668 did that also, but it didn't work.

Comment: ICO format is supported only in Windows.  So better convert it to XBM format.